# how to do one time trigger click with window.scroll jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my js code for a button that loads more posts from database.

`.getmore` is the class of the button. Now, I want to do that infinite scroll so that users don't need to click that button.

So I added the `window.scroll` function:

```
$('.getmore').trigger("click");
```

but it clicks 3 times at once. When manually clicked the button it works fine. But with scroll trigger it's getting same thing three times.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300) {
            $('.getmore').trigger("click");
        }
    }); 

    $('body').on('click','.getmore',function(){
        var lastelement = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getmore.php',
            data:'lastelement='+lastelement,
            beforesend: function(){
                $('.getmore').html('loading....');
            },       
            success: function(data){
                $('.getmore').remove();
                $('#recs') .append(data) ; 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I find it to be typical, at least on PC, for one mouse wheel "tick" to fire three scroll events.

Answer (score 2):

As MDN states:

> Since scroll events can fire at a high rate, the event handler
>   shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM
>   modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using
>   requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent

The basic approach they are proposing is a global variable that checks the state of the event. For your example, you can save a global variable called `fetching` that is set to `true` when the user scrolls, and set back to `false` when the new data is finished being fetched in the `success` callback. Finally, don't allow `.getmore` to be "clicked" if `fetching` is `true`.

Read the documentation for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Comment: I was just about to type an answer similar to yours. I think what is happening is the waiting time of fetching data from the server is taking too long so the scroll method is being called multiple times. Having a global variable to stop it executing the whole time should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
            $('yourbuttonIDorClass').trigger('click');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach with problems like this is to use deduction to rule out what is causing the issue:.

Rule out how many elements of class .getmore there are.

```
console.log($('.getmore').length); 
//Add this line under the .trigger('click');
```

**If there is > 1 this could be your problem.**

Rule out how many times the window scroll call back is called.

```
console.log('Scroll called'); 
//Add this line at the start of your $(window).scroll function.
```

**If scroll is called 3 times this could be your problem**

Check the event delegation approach you've taken isn't causing any weird issues.

Replace `$('body').on('click', '.getmore', function() {}` with `$('.getmore').click(function() {}`